# ExtJS TreePanel / TreeStore remoteSort property does not override frontend sorting

Tags: extjs

The `remoteSort` option does not seem to work in terms of respecting the network call returned data order. The frontend will override whatever the order is and resort based on how it "should" be sorted.

Is this a bug, or is there something else that should be implemented that I don't know about when using remoteSort on a treepanel?

Here is a snippet of the remote sort code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.stores.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    alias: 'store.myStore',
    storeId: 'myStoreID',
    remoteSort: true,
    remoteFilter: true,
    simpleSortMode: true,
    sortOnLoad: false,
    autoLoad: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        filterParam: 'query',
        url: 'myEndpoint',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            ...
```

The treepanel loads correctly (no errors), the remote call IS MADE. When selecting a column to sort by it DOES send the correct data to the backend. The data DOES return. It even displays fine. But the ORDER IS WRONG.

The order is being sorted by the FE, rather than using the order of array elements returned by the backend.

The ONLY thing I have found so far is disabling the sort from the front end entirely when the grid is rendered using the `afterrender` property, but this disables the ability to send ASC and DESC, and the sort gets stuck in the ASC mode. This also does not seem like the correct way to make this work for obvious reasons.

The Sencha docs do not offer enough guidance around this for me to debug it properly

Comment: Does the data return in the proper order and gets wrong only in the grid, or the data is in the wrong order in the response? Have you tried to call the backend with the same parameters in Postman for example?

Comment: The data returns in the proper order, the grid renders it incorrectly. Postman calls show the data also returned in the proper order. The easiest way to catch this is changing numbers to strings.

If a transform is performed on the data, the data will then sort incorrectly, not adhering to the sort order given by the backend, because JavaScript will have done a type conversion, and the data will sort lexically. I'm sure there are other ways to test this as well, such as returning "out of order" backend data, and watching the frontend sort it correctly.

Comment: It was classified as a bug in ExtJS5, [see here](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299060-TreeStore-always-sort-nodes). As I see this code is the same in `setupNodes` function, see [current version](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/src/TreeStore.js.html). Maybe you can try the fix as in the first link as an override.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a fairly easy fix, if I can figure out how to get it to stay in during a build. I'm kind of shocked this hasn't been fixed in 2 full release versions since it's a known issue and takes about three seconds to fix.

Comment: You can easily create an override of this ExtJS class, and override only this method. It won't cause any problems in build I think, I use several overrides because of similar issues :-) If you need help with that let me know.

Comment: If you put this as an answer I'll accept it. The solution was to change `|| sorters.length` to `&& sorters.length` in the ExtJS code. I can't believe this has been a bug for years

Comment: Never mind, I am happy that it works for you now. ExtJS can be like that, overrides are common to solve bugs like that. Good coding!

Comment: Not even fixed in 7.5.0.